# how to override gem generator template in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I know how to override a Rails template in a gem, but how can I override gem generator template in a Rails application

e.g.: https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/lib/generators/pundit/policy/templates/policy.rb

or

https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/master/lib/generators/rails/templates/decorator.rb

so that `rails g decorator Foo` would generate my template, not the gem native one

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Rails guide on generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates):

> In Rails 3.0 and above, generators don't just look in the source root
>   for templates, they also search for templates in other paths. And one
>   of them is lib/templates.

So, if you mimic the directory hierarchy of the gem/tamplate you are trying to override, rails will pick your template instead of the ones in the gem source

**Update:**

Now, the question is how to correctly mimic that hierarchy so rails pick your template up?

Well it turned out there is some kind of a rule | pattern for that, for example if you want to override a template in this path: `lib/generators/pundit/policy/templates/policy.rb`

You should place your template in `lib/templates/pundit/policy/policy.rb`

To override `lib/generators/rails/templates/decorator.rb`

You should place your template in `lib/templates/rails/decorator/decorator.rb`

**Update 2**

It seems that the pattern is flowing: `lib/templates/gem_name/generator_name/template_file_name.rb`

In case of Draper gem, the gem is enforcing itself to act like native Rails generator:

[/draper/lib/generators/rails/templates/decorator.rb](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/master/lib/generators/rails/templates/decorator.rb)

...so that's why we needed to use:

`lib/templates/rails/generator_name/template_file_name.rb`.

To override RSpec template generator of a Draper gem: 
`lib/templates/rspec/generator_name/template_file_name.rb`

...and so on

Comment: hey dude thx for helping. The thing is I tried every possible combination `lib/generators/pundit/policy/templates/policy.rb 
`, `lib/templates/policy.rb`, `lib/templates/haml/pundit/policy.html.haml` ... but the thing is the way how the gem is specifying the template path is like this https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/lib/generators/pundit/policy/policy_generator.rb

Comment: @equivalent8 It's a very wild guess but try `lib/templates/pundit/policy/policy.rb`

Comment: and for overriding Draper gem generator template I had to create:  `lib/templates/rails/decorator/decorator.rb`

Comment: @equivalent8 glad it worked:) i've updated my answer to cover what we found out

Comment: It seems to me the pattern is flowing `lib/templates/gem_name/generator_name/template_file_name.rb` In case of Draper gem, gem is enforcing itself to act like native Rails generator: `draper/lib/generators/rails/templates/decorator.rb` so that's why we needed to use `lib/templates/rails/generator_name/template_file_name.rb`

Comment: makes very good sense to me and i think you should edit the answer and put your pattern for ppl who will stuck on this in the future

Comment: A tip for discovering generator names: run the scaffold generator and note what other generators it invokes. i.e. for draper, the generator is actually named 'decorator'.

`invoke    decorator
 create      app/decorators/foo_decorator.rb
 invoke      rspec
 create        spec/decorators/foo_decorator_spec.rb`

Answer (score 1):

To customize templates for [twitter-bootswatch-rails](https://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails) gem's views generator, copy the whole content of [its template folder](https://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/bootswatch/themed/templates) into

```
lib/templates/bootswatch/themed
```

And run `rails g bootswatch:themed YourModels`

Answer (score 0):

To copy the default Pundit generators to your Rails project, you can use this command:

```
mkdir -p lib/templates/pundit/policy && \
cp $(bundle info pundit --path)/lib/generators/pundit/policy/templates/* lib/templates/pundit/policy
```