# How to write a rails generator that would override the default scaffold javascript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-generators

### Background:

- Currently writing a gem
- One of its features is that when `rails generate my_gem_name:install` is run, it (should) override the default javascript scaffold generated file (which is produced by `rails generate scaffold some_model_name`):

  - `app/assets/javascripts/some_model_name.coffee`

    - **From:**

      ```
      # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
      # All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
      # You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
      ```
    - **To:**

      ```
      # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
      # All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
      # You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

      SomeJavascriptCode.doSomething({model: 'SomeModelName'})
      ```

### Question:

- How to write the said Rails generator (from above) that would override the default scaffold javascript file that is created by `rails generate scaffold some_model_name`.
- Take note that the desired javascript file (as shown above), has dynamic contents; that is `{model: 'SomeModelName'}` should change & match correctly with the model name being generated.

### Attempts:

- I realised that there are two steps to solve this:

  - simply just being able to override the scaffold-generated javascript file
  - then, do something that would make the contents of said generated javascript file, to have "dynamic" contents.
- **1st step**:

  - Trying to write a generator that would copy my **template file** into Rails' `AssetsGenerator` template, eventually (hoping) to override it.

    ```
    # lib/generators/my_gem_name/install_generator.rb
    module MyGemName
      class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
        source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

        class_option :javascript_engine, desc: 'JS engine to be used: [js, coffee].'

        def copy_js_scaffold_template
          copy_file "javascript.#{javascript_engine}", "lib/templates/coffee-rails/assets/javascript.#{javascript_engine}"
        end

        private

        def javascript_engine
          options[:javascript_engine]
        end
      end
    end

    # lib/generators/my_gem_name/templates/javascript.coffee
    console.log('JUST TESTING!!!!!!!')
    ```

    - I temporarily used the path **lib/templates/coffee-rails/assets/javascript.coffee** just to test it out as the default `javascript_engine` is `coffee`. Probably that should change depending on `--javascript_engine`), but can't seem to make it work. 
      I got this path from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732373/how-to-override-gem-generator-template-in-rails-app/21732673) and then by referencing [THIS](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/blob/master/lib/rails/generators/coffee/assets/templates/javascript.coffee):

      > It seems that the pattern is flowing: 
      >   lib/templates/gem_name/generator_name/template_file_name.rb
    - From this [LINK](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/js/assets/templates/javascript.js), I also tried using the paths (but didnt work):

      - **lib/templates/rails/assets/javascript.coffee**
      - **lib/templates/rails/assets/coffee/javascript.coffee**
  - **2nd Step:** No attempts so far yet, as I'd like to make **1st Step** above to work first.

*All of my attempts above doesn't work: that is after both `rails generate my_gem_name:install` is ran, then running `rails generate scaffold some_model_name` still produces the original default javascript file, and not the expected `console.log('JUST TESTING!!!!!!!')` content (as I described above)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by the following. Hopefully, it would be helpful to anyone:

**For Step 1 (Overriding the javascript file):**

- The problem was the override-path is not

  `lib/templates/gem_name/generator_name/template_file_name.rb`

  but

  `lib/templates/module_name/generator_name/template_file_name.rb`

  This I verified after looking at [Coffe-Rails Generator Code](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/blob/master/lib/rails/generators/coffee/assets/assets_generator.rb) and then trying out the following (which worked: the scaffold-generated javascript file now gets overriden after running `rails generate my_gem_name:install` then followed by the scaffold generator `rails generate scaffold some_model_name`)

  ```
  # I temporarily hardcoded `coffee` as the `javascript_engine` to demonstrate, but `js` also works.
  copy_file "javascript.coffee", "lib/templates/coffee/assets/javascript.coffee"
  ```

**For Step 2 (Dynamic javascript file content):**

- After some trial-and-error, I noticed that you could actually insert `<%= ... %>` inside the javascript file, but then rename the template into a `ruby` file extension. The `template` seemingly gets rendered like how Rails views work when you insert `<%= ... %>` inside the file.

### Complete Solution Looks Like:

**lib/generators/my_gem_name/install_generator.rb**

```
module MyGemName
  class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

    class_option :javascript_engine, desc: 'JS engine to be used: [js, coffee].'

    def copy_js_scaffold_template
      copy_file "javascript.#{javascript_engine}.rb", "lib/templates/#{javascript_engine}/assets/javascript.#{javascript_engine}"
    end

    private

    def javascript_engine
      options[:javascript_engine]
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/generators/my_gem_name/templates/javascript.coffee.rb**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
SomeJavascriptCode.doSomething({model: '<%= singular_table_name.camelcase %>'})
```

Then, on terminal:

```
rails generate my_gem_name:install
  Running via Spring preloader in process 42586
        create lib/templates/coffee/assets/javascript.coffee

rails generate scaffold user email first_name last_name
  Running via Spring preloader in process 43054
        invoke active_record
        create   db/migrate/20170721152013_create_users.rb
        create   app/models/user.rb
        ...
        invoke assets
        invoke   coffee
        create     app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee
        ...

cat app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee
  # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
  # All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
  # You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
  SomeJavascriptCode.doSomething({model: 'User'})
```

Comment: If it doesn't work try terminating first `spring`; sometimes `spring` causes not to load the newly generated files inside lib/templates. I stop spring by running `bin/spring stop`